# El programa se salta el primer registro

Tags: c, dev-c++

estoy programando en C y tengo que hacer que quien ejecute el programa, ponga cuantos nombres de usuarios quiere ingresar. Aquí el problema:
El código no me deja ingresar el primer nombre y se salta directamente al segundo. Esto pasa cuando dejo el código para que el usuario pueda escoger cuantos nombres agregar (por ejemplo, si pone 5 nada más deja ingresar 4 y el primer nombre se lo salta), si pongo un número fijo como 6, puedo poner los 6 nombres sin problema, pero eso no cumple con lo que necesito. Aquí dejo el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int usuarios, i;
    
    printf("Ingrese el numero de usuarios: ");
    scanf("%i", &usuarios);
    char datos[usuarios][25];
    
    printf("Ingrese los nombres de los usuarios\n");
    for(i=0;i<usuarios;i++){
        printf("Nombre %i: ",i+1);
        fgets(datos[i], sizeof(datos[i]), stdin);
    }
    
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
        printf("%s", datos[j]);
    }
}
```

Dejo una imagen para una mayor comprensión del problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este es un problema clásico. El scanf sólo toma el número y "deja pasar" el salto de línea, entonces cuando entra al bucle el fgets recibe ese salto de linea como entrada y lo toma como una cadena de texto vacía. Tienes que agregar `%*c` para que el scanf se "coma" el salto de línea.

```
scanf("%i%*c", &usuarios);
```